# Support write operation in FUSE filesystem using FUSE-J

Tags: java, linux, file-io, fuse, filter-driver

I am working on developing a file system filter driver type of functionality in Linux. I am trying to explore and use  http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-j/?source=typ_redirect  for the very purpose.

However,FUSE-J does not support write,it provides a Read Only filesystem.Has anyone tried to implement write call ?

Is there any other java implementation for FUSE filesystem built on top of FUSE module?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily implement FUSE in java with [jnr-fuse](https://github.com/SerCeMan/jnr-fuse).

Project uses JNR, so you achieve full JNI performance with and ease of implementation.

Example of [hello-world filesystem](https://github.com/SerCeMan/jnr-fuse/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/serce/jnrfuse/examples/HelloFuse.java).